# Why is the menu bar not visible after returning from NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Accessory?

Tags: swift, nsapplication

When the application is hidden at launch using:

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().setActivationPolicy(NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Accessory)
```

It makes sense that the menu bar is not showing when the application is active. Since it doesn't have a dock representative.

However when in the preferences you switch back to:

```
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Regular)
```

It brings the dock back but the menu bar is still hidden.

I've tried making it active using:

```
NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
```

But this doesn't seem to have effect.